# How can I say "Credited as an inventor"

Tags: prepositions

How can I say "Credited as an inventor" as if I am part of many inventors

Comment: Note that there is a difference between being called *an* inventor and being named as *the* inventor (or one of *the inventors*) of something specific. I would consider editing your question to make it the definite pronoun if you're talking about a specific invention and want to avoid confusion.

Comment: I edited my question, please see. And, no, the questions has not been answered in this post, proposed as a possible duplicate

Comment: For whatever it may be, *credited* is not the word here. You could say "acknowledged" or "recognized" or one of many other alternatives.

Comment: Of course, *accredited* is not even a remote choice.

Comment: The best way to say "credited as an inventor" is to say "credited as an inventor". In fact that's the *only* way to say that. On a side note, stop saying you are *part* of other inventors. That's frankly quite gross. You can be part of a group. But you are not part of another person.

Comment: You either are or are not the inventor of a [thing]. Being credited as something is not exactly the same thing.

Comment: Co-inventor is the common term.

Comment: So "Credited as Co-inventor" is correct?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If, that's a **big if**, you meant to ask:

> How can I say "Credited as an inventor" when I am **part of a team of many** inventors?

then the answer would be:

> "Credited as **one of the inventors**."

HTH.

Comment: Can I say "Credited as a co-inventor" and would that be correct?

Comment: Sure. That works.

Answer (score -2):

If someone is **credited as** the inventor, he may not be the **actual inventor**.

credit **as** the inventor of means to consider x the inventor of. It is often used when the statement cannot be proven with 100% accuracy or the writer cannot show good proof of who the inventor actually was.

It's another way of saying: X is considered or deemed to be the inventor of Y.

> Question: Who is credited as inventing the telephone? Was it Alexander
>   Graham Bell, Elisha Gray, or Antonio Meucci?
>
> Answer: Alexander Graham Bell is often credited as the inventor of the
>   telephone since he was awarded the first successful patent. However,
>   there were many other inventors such as Elisha Gray and Antonio Meucci
>   who also developed a talking....[instrument? Sorry, you have to sign up but it is from the Library of Congress]

..

[credited as inventor](https://www.readworks.org/article/The-Inventor-of-the-Telephone/d67bbe5c-360e-4524-bb23-a0c33a390952#!articleTab:content/)

Comment: so "credited as an inventor" is ok, right? And it does not imply that I am the ONLY one, but part of a group of inventors?

Comment: "If someone is credited as the inventor, he may not be the actual inventor." Oh wait! Did you real mean it? Or maybe you meant to say something else (hopefully)?

Comment: @nmrlqa4 No, you ***are*** one of the inventors.  And not "part", one of the x. Part of a cake, part of a house, part of a story.

Comment: @Kris. No,  not "Oh wait!". I meant what I wrote.  ***Credited as an inventor*** is not ***is the inventor***.

Comment: All the same. Why would they *not* be? And how does that (hypothetical case) enter the picture here?

Comment: @Kris Do you want to be credited with criticizing me, or, are you critical of me?

Comment: @Lambie I don't know you. The issue is the Q, and the answer above. We are not to see the person but the thought.